# Get information from plt.hexbin

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have been using hexbing to try to improve the SPCF method, so for that I would need to get information from the plot to modify the data and then replot it with the new values.

The most important data I need to modify to replot is the number of points per cell and the C value of that grid cell.

Any way I can get such data?

Comment: oh - I see you've tagged pandas and geopandas. are you using pandas.DataFrame.hexbin? or plt.hexbin? my answer addressed the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html) returns a [`PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) object with methods `get_offsets` and `get_array` which provide exactly what you're looking for. From the hexbin docs:

> **Returns: [`PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection)**
> A PolyCollection defining the hexagonal bins.
>
> - **[`PolyCollection.get_offsets`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection.get_offsets)** contains a Mx2 array containing the x, y positions of the M hexagon centers.
> - **[`PolyCollection.get_array`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection.get_array)** contains the values of the M hexagons.
>
> If marginals is True, horizontal bar and vertical bar (both PolyCollections) will be attached to the return collection as attributes hbar and vbar.

## Example

As an example, I'll create a simple hexbin plot and grab the `PolyCollection` object returned by `plt.hexbin`:

```py
In [2]: x = np.linspace(1, 20, 500)

In [3]: y = np.log(x) + np.random.random(size=500) - 0.5

In [4]: coll = plt.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=20)
```

[image: hexbin plot]

You can explore the collection object and grab the arrays returned by `get_offsets()` and `get_array()`:

```py
In [23]: type(coll)
Out[23]: matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection

In [24]: offsets = coll.get_offsets()

In [25]: offsets
Out[25]:
array([[ 9.99999981e-01, -3.48964611e-01],
       [ 9.99999981e-01, -3.91102264e-03],
       [ 9.99999981e-01,  3.41142565e-01],
       ...
       [ 1.95250000e+01,  2.58399089e+00],
       [ 1.95250000e+01,  2.92904448e+00],
       [ 1.95250000e+01,  3.27409806e+00]])

In [26]: arr = coll.get_array()

In [27]: arr
Out[27]:
masked_array(data=[ 2.,  4.,  0.,  ...,  7.,  2.,  4.],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=1e+20)

In [28]: offsets.shape
Out[28]: (472, 2)

In [29]: arr.shape
Out[29]: (472,)
```

You could manipulate these arrays however you want, and then plot them again using the x, y, and `C` count argument to hexbin. If you don't change the values of offsets and arr, this plots the exact same image:

```py
In [30]: plt.hexbin(offsets[:, 0], offsets[:, 1], C=arr, gridsize=20)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer I really apreciate. I have been trying to run it with my code but because I do have the values C there is no way for me to get the 'arr' in that case because 'arr' is the value but I also need the number of points in each cell. I tried running it with only x and y but the 'len(arr)' is not the same as in x y and c hexbin because there are extra hexagons with values of 0

Comment: can you provide your code? I don't really understand your issue. you should still be able to get the collection even if you provide C

Comment: I have actually solved it already. I could get the offsets and the arr without problem. But I wanted to change the arr values based on other arr with the same set of x and y points. So I just did multiple collections with different `reduce_C_function` to get the different `arr` I needed to change that. The problem was in the way `arr` is usually obtained. Thanks for your atention